# Python - как сдвинуть изображения графиков?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Есть скрипт, который рисует скользящую среднюю от списка.
Но график средней рисуется некорректно - последнее значение средней
должно быть над последним значением списка. Как мне быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[10,2,19,43,55,67,27,108,99,110]
n=4
ret=np.cumsum(x)
ret[n:]=ret[n:]-ret[:-n]
res=ret[n-1:]/n
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(res)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
print(res)
```

Comment: а как их скорректировать? Значения средних считаются правильно - перепроверял вручную

Answer (score 3):

Там где вы её нарисовали она точно не может быть. Но можно её сдвинуть вправо при рисовании `res`:

```
plt.plot(np.arange(n-1, len(x)), res)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ вот это добавлено
```

Скользящее среднее всегда имеет меньше точек, чем исходный график, на размер "окна" по которому оно считается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]